# Parallel local testing using selenium, specflow, nunit without selenium grid

Tags: c#, selenium, parallel-processing, nunit, specflow

I am trying to make tests running parallel on my local machine without using selenium grid. My problem is with Firefox driver. I have two tests on the same website. When I execute below code for FirefoxDriver one test is abadoned and I have timeout error. When I am executing using ChromeDriver or EdgeDriver there is no issue.

```
[Binding]
public class Hooks
{
    public IWebDriver driver;
    private IObjectContainer objectContainer;

    public Hooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        this.objectContainer = objectContainer;
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void BeforeScenario()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs(driver);
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void AfterScenario()
    {
        driver.Close();
    }
```

Scope of parallelism is set to [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]

Error:

```
Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55285/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing.
  ----> System.TimeoutException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

  Stack Trace: 
HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
WebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
FirefoxDriver.ctor(FirefoxDriverService service, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
FirefoxDriver.ctor(String geckoDriverDirectory, FirefoxOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
FirefoxDriver.ctor(String geckoDriverDirectory, FirefoxOptions options)
FirefoxDriver.ctor(String geckoDriverDirectory)
Hooks.BeforeScenario() line 57
BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
SafeBindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
LoginFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
LoginFeature.StandardUserIsAbleToLogIn() line 9
--TaskCanceledException
HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
HttpCommandExecutor.MakeHttpRequest(HttpRequestInfo requestInfo)
HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
--TimeoutException
--TaskCanceledException
HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
--IOException
AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--SocketException

  Standard Output: 
-> error: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55285/session timed out after 60 seconds. (62,2s)
Given website is opened
-> skipped because of previous errors
When user provides credentials
-> skipped because of previous errors
Then is successfuly logged in
-> skipped because of previous errors
-> error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (0,0s)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions/ ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling the drivers and PC restart everything started working. I forgot about this fundamental rule to turn on and off :)

Comment: It might have been due to your browser being auto-updated without installing the updated drivers. Generally, the first step in fixing really wonky errors like this one is to update your drivers.